# OutOfMemory Error java heap space

Tags: java, memory-management, anti-patterns

I'm using this statement

```
//some code
int a[][]=new int[5000000][5000000];
//some code
```

and running it with command

```
java -mx512m Test
```

It is giving  OutOFMemoryError: Java Heap space indicating the line number of the mentioned statement in the stacktrace

How do i solve this problem

Edit:
I'm trying to solve a [practice problem on codechef](http://codechef.com/problems/PRIMPATT)

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve with a 25 trillion ints matrix?

Comment: Goodness, did you really think you could allocate, and iterate over, 100TB of data in the 3 seconds your algorithm is allowed to take?

Comment: _First_ make it work, _then_ optimize!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the data structure you are looking for is a sparse matrix.  Store your elements along with their coordinates in a map data structure (eg. `Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Integer>>` for a 2d sparse array) and just assume anything not in the map is zero.

Comment: Yes I think i'll go this way.. it'll save memory as well as iteration time

Comment: +1 for the idea of a sparse matrix, though I'd suggest using a key type that doesn't require so much complication.  Like `Map<Point, Integer>` or some other purpose-made key class that is just a container for the two ints.

Answer (score 8):

You may need to consider an approach to your problem which requires less memory.

From Google Calculator (assuming a 64bit integer size):

```
(5 000 000^2) * 64 bits = 186 264.515 gigabytes
```

Comment: A java int is sepcified as 32 bits though.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the details of Java, so I assumed the default integer size for a 64-bit computer. So I might be off by 93,000 GB or so.

Answer (score 5):

I've faced same problem with Eclips concern Java heap 
and the solution was to revise the mx512m into mx4096m or mx2048m (expand the maximum allowed limit of memory) 
so in your case try the command
java -mx4096m Test which will allow java to use 4 GB of your ram

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's 25 trillion ints, each of which takes 4 bytes, so 100 trillion bytes overall.  Easiest solution is to buy ~90 terabytes of RAM and a 64 bit OS.

Seriously though, the correct solution is probably to allocate a more reasonable data structure that can store the data more efficiently, assuming that you don't actually need to load 90 terabytes of data into RAM at once.  Perhaps if you post more about the problem, we can give a better answer?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to solve a practice problem on codechef http://www.codechef.com/problems/PRIMPATT/. I think i will need a matrix of this size. Any help is appriciated

Comment: If solving the problem by modeling the entire field in memory leads you to need a 90 terabyte array, that's a pretty good signal that there's a better way to solve the problem.  I would think you would have to figure out a way to determine whether a given square is black, without actually simulating the entire process that the robot goes through.

Comment: Yes i think i should change the approach. But one thing If i convert the type from int to byte will it help?

Comment: You'd only be allocating 1B * 5M * 5M = 25 TB. Want to squezze it into a bit? It's still 3TB. Do you really think this'll get you anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Amongst the other answers, you have a typo in your command.

It should be: `java -Xmx512M Test`

Answer (score 0):

You are using too much memory.  Use less or have more.  Each int element is 32-bits.  And your memory limit of 512MB is much less than you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

for int[5000000][5000000] you need 100000000000000B or 100000GB. So you only can wait about 100 years when something like that is going to be possible.

Comment: You really think it'll take 100 years for 100000 GB to be economical?  How about a friendly wager?

Comment: The winner gets a 10000 Gb USB key.

Answer (score 0):

You need a more enlightened data structure. Unless you actually NEED 25 trillion integers, which is doubtful.

Answer (score 0):

That's a matrix with 5 million columns and 5 million rows. Is that really what you wanted?